# Link to a section of a page from another page

Tags: html, css

How do I link to a certain section on the home page from another page.

The section I'm trying to target on the home page is:

```
<section id="service-section" class="service-section content-section">
```

I'm linking to it from another page like this:

```
<a href="index.html/#service-section">Services</a>
```

But when I click the link nothing happens. Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the slash:

```
<a href="index.html#service-section">Services</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you by any chance tried:

```
<a href="index.html#service-section">Services</a>
```

I don't think there should be a "/".